# Python generate range array with random step size

Tags: python, numpy, random, range

Goals: to Initialize an array with pre-defined size with a random number. 
I have try this way and working:

```
xa = np.empty(100)
xa[0] = random.random()
for i in range(1,100):
    xa[i] = xa[i-1] + random.random()
```

My question: Is there any better way to do it? maybe without the for loop?

Comment: it looks good to me.

Comment: When you create `np.empty(100)` it's already all random though...? I'm not sure I follow your question. Did you just want each subsequent element to be larger than the previous?

Comment: `cumsum` on a random array of steps?

Comment: is it an array of 100 random numbers? or does it have any specific conditions?

Comment: To elaborate on @hpaulj comment: `xa = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(100))`

Comment: This is exactly what I was after: `xa = np.cumsum(np.random.rand(100))` does exactly what I wanted in the most succinct way.  Thank you!!

Comment: Consider accepting Daniel's answer then (which is more elaborate than @hpaulj and my comments), so that others can quickly find a solution to problems like yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are using numpy the code in your question is equivalent to:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

xa = np.cumsum(np.random.random(100))
print(xa[:5])
```

**Output**

```
[0.37454012 1.32525443 2.05724837 2.65590685 2.81192549]
```

But if what you want if something that returns a range (like the one from the [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function), but with a random step you could do something like this:

```
xa = np.cumsum(np.random.randint(100, size=(100,)))
print(xa[:5])
```

**Output**

```
[ 62 157 208 303 306]
```

Note that in both cases only the first 5 numbers are printed. Also in both cases the step is positive.

**Further**

1. Documentation on [cumsum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html), [randint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and [random](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.random.html).

Answer (score 2):

Simple one-liner

```
import random 
xa = random.sample(range(1, 101), 100)
```

Comment: That's great answer. Don't forget to assign the result to `xa` ;)

Comment: I believe random.random() returns a float between 0 and 1. So this wont return the same as the OP.

Comment: this is the output what I got
    [86, 15, 91, 75, 65, 46, 81, 45, 94, 3, 61, 28, 96, 29, 5, 100, 62, 89, 20, 92, 32, 76, 55, 87, 84, 27, 6, 11, 80, 95, 90, 67, 9, 41, 59, 48, 54, 42, 79, 52, 24, 93, 1, 19, 18, 13, 50, 71, 49, 97, 12, 78, 25, 66, 47, 38, 40, 33, 68, 26, 53, 8, 16, 43, 21, 70, 72, 56, 7, 63, 37, 58, 51, 34, 14, 69, 64, 83, 73, 4, 85, 2, 77, 31, 30, 82, 35, 44, 98, 17, 99, 74, 88, 36, 10, 60, 22, 23, 39, 57]

Comment: The output of the OP does not return integers

Answer (score 1):

You also can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) function:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import numpy as np
import random

xa = np.empty(100)
xa[0] = random.random()

xa = list(accumulate(xa, lambda x, y: x + random.random()))
```

I am not quite sure that this is what you need, but it computes every element with `prev + random.random()` like you wrote in your question.

Comment: Great answer.  Works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this better than your code

```
import random
xa = [None] * 100
xa[0] = random.random()
for i in xrange(1, 100):
        xa[i] = xa[i-1] + random.random()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
import random
n = 100   # your array size
xa = [random.random() for _ in range(n)]
```

Again as mentioned, `np.empty(100)` would already give you a fully random array of the size.  What is the issue with `np.empty()`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not quite what I was after.  This just returns a list of random numbers, not the cumulative sum of random numbers I was after.  Also worth mentioning that np.empty(100)isn't actually random, but garbage (whatever information was at the memory addresses assigned to the array), which I believe is different.